# How can I solve this higher degree first order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find all solutions of the differential equation:

$$
(dy/dx)^2 + e^y +cos(x) + 3 = 0
$$

I'm having trouble figuring out where to start. Examples I've seen have polynomial terms instead of exponential and trig terms.

Thank you.

Comment: Is $y$ a real function? At least one of the first 3 terms has to be smaller than or equal $-1$. What does that say about the domain of the equation?

Answer (score 0):

Since $e^y \ge 0$ and $\cos x \ge -1$ we have

$$ (y')^2 + e^y + \cos x + 3 \ge 2 $$

So there is no solution.